# Pass Data from directive into controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which gets the height and width of a div and I wish to pass this data in my controller. How can this be done?

```
 angular.module('Module', [])
     .controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
         function($scope, $rootScope,) {



     }]).directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
         return {
             restrict: 'A',

             link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                 scope.height = element.prop('offsetHeight');
                 scope.width = element.prop('offsetWidth');
             }
         };
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Html:

```
<input type="text" your-custom-text-field ng-model="textValue" ng-tooltip-max="5">
```

> Directive:

```
yourApp.directive('yourDirName', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'ngToolTipMax': '&',
            'ngModel': '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.onChange = function () {
                scope.ngModelValue = scope.model;
            };   
        }
    };
});
```

> Isolated Scope: pass some values from the parent scope to the directives
>
> There’re 3 types of prefixes AngularJS provides
>
> 1. "@" ( Text binding / one-way binding )
> 2. "=" ( Direct model binding / two-way binding )
> 3. "&" ( Behaviour binding / Method binding )
>
> All these prefixes receives data from the attributes of the directive element.
>
> get Help from http://jsfiddle.net/shidhincr/pJLT8/10/light/

Mastering the Scope of the Directives in AngularJS

http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: This doesn't explain how I can pass this data from the directive into the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

To make the custom directive more versatile, I have it read the value of the `my-directive` attribute and use that name for the scope object.

In this example I create two boxes, "boxA" and "boxB", and put their height and width on the scope.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<pre>
green box size = {{boxA.height}},{{boxA.width}}
red   box size = {{boxB.height}},{{boxB.width}}
</pre>
    <div my-directive="boxA" style="height:50px;width:100px;background:green">
    </div>
    <div my-directive="boxB" style="height:80px;width:20px;background:red">
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
             restrict: 'A',
             link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                   scope[attr.myDirective] = {};
                   var d = scope[attr.myDirective];
                   d.height = element.prop('offsetHeight');
                   d.width = element.prop('offsetWidth');
                   console.log(scope);
                  }
   };
});
```

Result

```
green box size = 50,100
red   box size = 80,20
```

[The **Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9I19HTPfx8w0WdMsB5z2?p=preview)